# mathematical expression entered in one text box and display its result in other text box

Tags: c#

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Text1.Text));//here is the exception i am getting.
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Text1.Text));
char c = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToString(Text1.Text));
int result = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Text2.Text));

if (c == '+')
{
    result = a + b;
    Text2.Text += result;
}
else if (c == '-')
{
    result = a - b;
    Text2.Text += result;
}
else if (c == '/')
{
    result = a / b;
    Text2.Text += result;
}
else if (c == '*')
{
    result = a * b;
    Text2.Text += result;
}
else
    return;
```

I am getting a format exception for this code as "Input string was not in a correct format". I know this is a simple question but i didn't get answer any where.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line raises the exception, and what is the input that causes it?

Comment: Can you please post exception line ? it will help to give answer

Comment: Also, the `.Text` property of a TextBox is already a string, no need to `Convert.ToString` it.. and you appear to be trying to load a, b, c from the same textbox?

Comment: int a = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Text1.Text));
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Text1.Text)); this is where the exception is raising....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly this is not a pretty one but it will give the job done for numbers that are positive and at most 3 digits.

I tested these values: `5+2` result `10`, `50*2` result `100`, `50*2+1` result `101`

See my **[Demo](http://ideone.com/DZgZGn)**

```
        string[] num = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text, @"\-|\+|\*|\/").Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray(); // get Array for numbers
        string[] op = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text, @"\d{1,3}").Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray(); // get Array for mathematical operators +,-,/,*
        int numCtr = 0, lastVal=0; // number counter and last Value accumulator
        string lastOp = ""; // last Operator
        foreach (string n in num)
        {
            numCtr++;
            if (numCtr == 1)
            {
                lastVal = int.Parse(n); // if first loop lastVal will have the first numeric value
            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastOp)) // if last Operator not empty
                {
                    // Do the mathematical computation and accumulation
                    switch (lastOp) 
                    {
                        case "+":
                            lastVal = lastVal + int.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "-":
                            lastVal = lastVal - int.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "*":
                            lastVal = lastVal * int.Parse(n);
                            break;
                        case "/":
                            lastVal = lastVal + int.Parse(n);
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
            int opCtr = 0;
            foreach (string o in op)
            {
                opCtr++;
                if (opCtr == numCtr) //will make sure it will get the next operator
                {
                    lastOp = o;  // get the last operator
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(lastVal.ToString());
```

Comment: thank you a lot...it worked for single input but i am looking for multiple inputs that means after one expression has been executed in first text box i must be able to enter another expression and get the output both the expressions and outputs must be visible in text boxes...

Comment: case "/" should use division?

Answer (score 3):

First off, `Convert.ToString(someString)` is useless. Secondly, you will actually have to parse the input from `Text1` to get all the relevant pieces out.

The simplest way is to split the string by some delimiter:

```
string[] parts = Text1.Text.Split(' ');
int a = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
int b = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]);
char c = parts[1][0];
```

This will handle any input in the form `123 + 456` (with exactly one space between each part). Alternatively, you could use a regular expression:

```
var match = Regex.Match(Text1.Text, @"^\s*(\d+)\s*([+/*-])\s*(\d+)\s*$");
if (match.Success)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[3].Value);
    char c = match.Groups[2].Value[0];
}
```

Finally, there's no point in parsing `Text2` if you're not going to do anything with the result.

Comment: i am getting the exception for these two lines    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Text1.Text));
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Text1.Text));

Comment: @user2499557 See my answer. Use my code to get a, b, and c.

Comment: after p.s.w.g's code, you if conditions should work. and in the if conditions, dont forget to convert result to string before assigning it to text2.text

Comment: but problem is i can use only one operator at a time cant use expression like 2+3-4*3.